# how to query joined collection in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

so i have two collection's in my mongodb: 1st is `user collection`, which contains user info and looks like this.

**User collection**

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e463237c74759a880443a78"},
"name":"vatsalay khobragade",
"email":"vatsalayvk1434@gmail.com",
"password":{"$binary{"base64":"JDJiJDEyJDl6WGlRVWNnWWdIWFFXYzIzeEQ4MWVKVnpsUzNWNWI5SkpmMGxab1k0TDRlakVIeDl1LjdD","subType":"00"}},
"address":"rajnandgaon",
"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[{"$numberDouble":"20.9727404"},{"$numberDouble":"80.69155548263583"}]},
"fulladdress":"Rajnandgaon, Chhattisgarh, India",
"isVerified":true,
"facebook":null,
"instagram":null
},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e5d35825738ca47fbf99484"},
"name":"vatsalay k",
"email":"vatsalaykhobragade1234@gmail.com",
"password":{"$binary":{"base64":"JDJiJDEyJFpKTTU4bTVtOHBxTW5YRm1GU1hwWU8wenAuWVUuUGg0U2wyT044MFFweFUzc01oY2Mzckwy",
"subType":"00"}},
"address":"bhilai",
"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[{"$numberDouble":"21.2120677"},{"$numberDouble":"81.3732849"}]},
"fulladdress":"Bhilai, Durg Tahsil, Durg, Chhattisgarh, 490036, India",
"isVerified":true,
"donateList":[[{"bookid":{"$oid":"5e5d365b5738ca47fbf99485"}}]]
}
```

2nd is `books collection`: which contains book's, donated and requested by users. which looks like this.

**book's collection**

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e2af0e82b9a4157f000cad8"},
"bookname":"javascript book",
"bookdesc":"its a javascript book","donatedby":"vatsalay khobragade"
},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e315dc9a92ad961795d9718"},
"bookname":"python 3 book",
"bookdesc":"armin rochnaher",
"donatedby":"vatsalay khobragade"
}
```

so i am joining these two collections using `$lookup` method. which  is desired and after joining these two collections i am getting something like this:

**result after joining two collections**

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e463237c74759a880443a78'),
'name': 'vatsalay khobragade',
'email': 'vatsalayvk1434@gmail.com',
'password': b'$2b$12$9zXiQUcgYgHXQWc23xD81eJVzlS3V5b9JJf0lZoY4L4ejEHx9u.7C', 'address': 'rajnandgaon',
'location': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [20.9727404, 80.69155548263583]},
'fulladdress': 'Rajnandgaon, Chhattisgarh, India', 'isVerified': True, 'facebook': None,
'instagram': None,
'books': [{'_id': ObjectId('5e2af0e82b9a4157f000cad8'), 'bookname': 'javascript book', 'bookdesc': 'its a javascript book', 'donatedby': 'vatsalay khobragade'},
{'_id': ObjectId('5e314eed3f84e7cf7f0a5bfe'),
'bookname': 'biology book', 'bookdesc': 'its a biology book\r\n', 'donatedby': 'vatsalay khobragade'},
{'_id': ObjectId('5e315dc9a92ad961795d9718'), 'bookname': 'python 3 book', 'bookdesc': 'armin rochnaher', 'donatedby': 'vatsalay khobragade'}]
}
```

so what i want is, I want to query this joined result by the **key** `bookname` and i want to show the information it has in it. Like `bookname`, `donatedby`. How to achieve this in mongodb ?? Thanks.

Comment: what is the issue or question here ?

Comment: oh sorry for that. i edited the question.